# How to decrease response time of first db request in MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, query-performance

My First database call is taking too long sometimes to render the view / Page. it takes around 10-12 seconds then second time its fast like 500 ms then 200 ms. Below is sample of code that i am running in several cases in my project. I am using stored Procedures. My project structure is default mvc structure.

I have checked Running StoredProcedure in Databse. It average take 200-300 ms then why complete page takes around 12 seconds to load. Is it problem with my hosting or how can i diagnose this problem.

```
using (WebMatrix.Data.Database db1 = WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open("SQLTestDB"))
{
var PromoDetails = db1.Query("exec GetListingPromosV2 @0", id).ToList();
List<VMListingPromos> Lst = new List<VMListingPromos>();

foreach (var item in PromoDetails)
{
    VMListingPromos Listing_Promo = new VMListingPromos();
    Listing_Promo.PromoTitle = item.PromoName;
    Listing_Promo.Amount = item.Value;
    Listing_Promo.ExpirationDate = (item.ExpirationDate == null ? "NoDate" :     item.ExpirationDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    Listing_Promo.StartDate = (item.StartDate == null ? "NoDate" : item.StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    Listing_Promo.ListingPromoID = item.ID;
    Listing_Promo.status = item.status;
    Lst.Add(Listing_Promo);
}
return Lst;
}
```

Comment: What timings do you get in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: ok let me check please

Comment: in db my sp is taking 200-300 ms

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may not have an open db connection pool on your first request. You could try setting a minimum number of connection pools via the connection string, that way your app will always keep an open connection.

Example Connection String in web.config:
`<add name="WriteConnection" connectionString="Data Source=my-server-name;Database=my_database;User ID=user;Password=password;Application Name=app_name;Min Pool Size=1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/8xx3tyca(v=vs.71)

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Sorry but i checked it didn't meant so much any difference